# how to compare the row of table 1 with the column of table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

2 tables

product:

```
prod_id   prod_name
1          Citrus-fruit
2          bread
3          margarine
4          Ready-Soup
5          Tropical-fruit
```

trans:

```
trans_id   prod_1           prod_2          prod_3            prod_4
1          Citrus-fruit     margarine       Ready-Soup
2          bread            margarine       Tropical-fruit
3          Citrus-fruit     bread           margarine         Tropical-fruit
4          bread            Tropical-fruit
5          Citrus-fruit     bread           margarine         Tropical fruit
```

So I want to compare prod_name = prod_1 and return prod_id,  prod_name = prod_2 and return prod_id  and so on

I tried a mysql query as

```
select product.prod_id from `product` ,'trans' where product.prod_name=trans.prod_1;
```

the above query doesn't work properly.

My expectation is:

```
prod_1  prod_2    prod_3   prod_4
1        3         4
2        3         5
1        2         3         5
2        5
1        2         3         5
```

and then convert above `table` into `text file`  as:

```
1,3,4
2,3,5
1,2,3,5
2,5
1,2,3,5
```

Thank you

Comment: What doesn't work? What are you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: what did you mean not work properly?

Comment: You can answer the "did not work" questions by providing the desired output for your sample database content and explain the difference to the output you got, which you should also provide here.

Comment: Java doesn't seem to be even remotely related.. I removed that tag

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are expecting.However, you can try that:

```
select * from product inner join trans on product.prod_name=trans.prod_1;
```

You should get back the elements that are matching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate the names with the products' ids, you will have to join the `trans` table with the `product` table once for each column

```
select  p1.prod_id, p2.prod_id, p3.prod_id, p4.prod_id
from    trans t1
left join
        product p1
on      t1.prod_1 = p1.prod_name
left join
        product p2
on      t1.prod_2 = p2.prod_name
left join
        product p3
on      t1.prod_3 = p3.prod_name
left join
        product p4
on      t1.prod_4 = p4.prod_name
order by t1.trans_id
```

The `left join` is required because in your sample table some products seem to be missing, so using `inner joins` would not return you all those rows with at least one product missing.

**Edit**

If you can't / don't want to add the commas at application level (which I would suggest) you can achieve the same by changing the query above like this

```
select  trim(trailing ',' from concat_ws(',', coalesce(p1.prod_id, ''),
                                              coalesce(p2.prod_id, ''),
                                              coalesce(p3.prod_id, ''),
                                              coalesce(p4.prod_id, '')
                                        )
            )
from    trans t1
left join
        product p1
on      t1.prod_1 = p1.prod_name
left join
        product p2
on      t1.prod_2 = p2.prod_name
left join
        product p3
on      t1.prod_3 = p3.prod_name
left join
        product p4
on      t1.prod_4 = p4.prod_name
order by t1.trans_id;
```

You can see both version in action **[here](http://rextester.com/HERZ21256)**

Comment: Sir, I tried this code but it is not giving the expected result

Comment: @Ruchi I think it was mostly fine, but I edited it with a couple improvements

Comment: Thank you so much  ,I tried this code and it is  working as  per my expectation  . i want to remove this line  "trim(trailing ',' from concat_ws(',', coalesce(p1.prod_id, ''), coalesce(p2.prod_id, ''), coalesce(p3.prod_id, ''), coalesce(p4.prod_id, '')))"  from saving in a row .Can you please guide me.

Comment: @Ruchi If you want a different column for each ID (like `1, 3, 4, NULL` for the first row) you can use my first query. If you want the values separated by comma, that line with `trim(...)` is how you do that.

Comment: Actually I am creating a button in java  ,when I push the button it should generate the above result and create the text file which include 1,3,4 and then give this text file as the input to the  Apriori algorithm

Comment: @Ruchi as I said in my first edit, I'd suggest you use my first query to retrieve the data in tabular form, then concatenate the fields and write them on a file at application level (in the Java code in your case)